# Cannot flash Wemos D1 using NodeMCU

Tags: esp8266, firmware, nodemcu

I am trying to flash Wemos D1 mini (ESP8266) using NodeMCU according to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zwp9E37ioVw&t=53). Pins NodeMCU → Wemos:

- RX → RX
- TX → TX
- D3 → D3
- RST → RST
- 3.3V → 3.3V
- GND → GND
- EN → GND

When flashing Wemos LED is blinking (probably as a response for reset), but flash process does not start. [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) writes to log the following:

```
Uploading .pioenvs\esp8266\firmware.bin
esptool.py v2.6
Serial port COM11
Connecting........_____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____....._____
A fatal error occurred: Failed to connect to ESP8266: Timed out waiting for packet header
*** [upload] Error 2
```

P.S.:

- I flash Wemos because there is a problem with flashing it using build-in USB (one transistor was not soldered by error). Hence I use NodeMCU as USB-TTL converter.
- There is no problem in USB cable. I used it successfully to flash another Wemos board (which has no defects) using VS Code (same procedure/method).
- I tried to power Wemos with a separate power, but that does not help.
- Similar question: [ESP-01 module unable to flash or communicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469232/esp-8266-01-module-unable-to-flash-or-communicate) – suggests wire 3.3V → RST (Wemos).

What can I try additionally?

**Update on Dec 2022:**

Just want to confirm that D1 Mini can be flashed with external [USB-TTL converter](https://easyeda.com/dma_k/ch340e-uart) by connecting 3.3V and GND to D1 Mini, and TX to RX, RX to TX (cross link). D3 (GPIO0) should be grounded before D1 Mini is started e.g. before powering USB-TTL converter / connecting USB.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: You must find a better way of making connections to the D1 board. I don't think there's any point in talking about other sources of errors until that gets fixed.

Comment: Your video seems for ESP8266-01, which is very old. Is your D1 Mini 12?

Comment: I have spent some 100 hours testing out ESP8266 (mostly -12, less -01)  There are many tricks you need to be aware of. I have a blog of about 100+ posts sharing my newbie learning experience. You might like to browse my posts: 

(1) ***Testing ESP8266-01/12*** - rpi.org.forum 2108sep29,
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=32&t=219744&p=1371842&hilit=esp8266+12+tlfong01#p1371377

(2) rpi.org.forum Search found 155 matches: esp8266 tlfong01 Searched query: esp8266 tlfong01,
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/search.php?keywords=esp8266+tlfong01. Happy learning. Cheers.

Comment: after you make the wires have real contact, you have to put the NodeMcu esp8266 in flashing mode. use esptool command line switches to suppress resetting of the Wemos D1 to flashing mode

Comment: I assume you are using the following to flash your ESP8266-12. (1) D1 Mini ESP8266-12, (2) ESPTool v2.6. You other question is on ESP8266-01 which, as I said, is very out of date and had tricky problems already sorted out in 12 models.

Comment: One more thing. Your photo seems to show that that female jump cables is NOT connected to any soldered males pins.  Then the electrical contacts are not reliable and might causing intermittent failures.  ***I would suggest to solder the male pin headers***.

Comment: Dear all, thanks for your advises. I have soldered all pins on Wemos D1, but it didn't help. Wemos still blinks with LED but does not want to enter the programming/flashing mode.
@tlfong01
Thanks for the links. I read a few but how that is related to the problem I posted? I have two Wemos boards and one of two flashes just fine via USB with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) (same method), another has one transistor not soldered hence signal from CH380 does not pass to the ESP. Any advise is welcomed!

Comment: I tried some examples of what you are trying to do and I got to the same position as you. But, it does look like the NodeMCU is not acting properly in the D3 and Reset.  I was able to upload code using Node MCU to ESP-01 but not to D1 Mini. Here are the videos I did. The only way I was succeed to upload code to D1 Mini was using the programmer(https://www.ebay.ca/itm/203304682591, https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B08YJ6SS3H?ref=myi_title_dp). Follow the videos https://youtu.be/mjnaPSykJNA, https://youtu.be/ABMfip3s8sU, https://youtu.be/cEumXDaNibQ

Comment: I just thought maybe there is a chance to [program D1 Mini with Arduino](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q-KIpFIbRMk&t=60s)? I also have [CH340E module](https://easyeda.com/dma_k/ch340e-uart), but I am not sure how to switch it to 3.3V mode (does not have a dedicated jumper, probably needs soldering).

Comment: Just want to confirm that D1 Mini can be flashed with [external USB-TTL converter](https://easyeda.com/dma_k/ch340e-uart) by connecting 3.3V and GND to D1 Mini, and TX to RX, RX to TX (cross link). D3 (GPIO0) should be grounded *before D1 Mini is started* e.g. before powering USB-TTL converter / connecting USB.

Answer (score 0):

rx -- tx

tx -- rx

et non

rx -- rx

tx -- rx

Comment: English only please

Comment: Believe me, it's not about RX-TX wiring. D3 (GPIO0) should be grounded before the board is started. The one can use external USB-TTL converter to flash it.